# "Diamond" join in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables with columns:

```
TABLE1: id
TABLE2: id, t4_ref, t1_ref
TABLE3: id, t4_ref, t1_ref
TABLE4: id, type
```

What I would like to do is to get IDs from FIRST table, but only if there exists TABLE2 OR TABLE3 reference to this ID (at t1_ref columns) AND "type" in TABLE4 is equal to something.

I don't know if the title is good enough but it's like making diamond for me - firstly joining two tables with one, and then one with those two.

I don't know how to tackle this properly, I tried something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_ref
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.t1_ref
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 AS t4 ON t2.t4_ref = t4.id OR t3.t4_ref = t4.id
WHERE t4.type = 'something';
```

And also:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_ref
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.t1_ref
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 AS t4 ON t2.t4_ref = t4.id
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 AS t4 ON t3.t4_ref = t4.id
WHERE t4.type = 'something';
```

The query run, but it is so slow, that I cannot see result, and I'm wondering if it really must be THAT slow or I'm doing something wrong. Mind that I have few hundred thousands of records in each table. Any ideas how to tackle this "diamond" join?

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN?

Comment: LEFT JOIN is probably the culprit here as it creates way more result rows than you expect.

Comment: is it possible that an `id` in table 1 exists in both tables 2 and 3?

Comment: INNER JOIN yields me 0 results. @ninesided Yes. There are no rules really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 AS t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        TABLE2 AS t2
        JOIN TABLE4 AS t4 
            ON t2.t4_ref = t4.id
    WHERE
        t1.id = t2.t1_ref
        AND t4.type = 'something'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        TABLE3 AS t3
        JOIN TABLE4 AS t4
            ON t3.t4_ref = t4.id
    WHERE
        t1.id = t3.t1_ref
        AND t4.type = 'something'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this using two `exists` clauses:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table3 t3 join
                   table4 t4
                   on t3.t1_ref = t1.id and
                      t3.t4_ref = t4.id and t4.type = 'something'
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from table2 t2 join
                   table4 t4
                   on t2.t1_ref = t1.id and
                      t2.t4_ref = t4.id and t4.type = 'something'
             );
```

For efficiency, you want the following indexes:  `table2(t1_ref, t4_ref)`, `table3(t1_ref, t4_ref)`, `table4(id, type)`.